# Block overwriting NuGet artifacts in Artifactory

Tags: nuget, artifactory, jfrog-mission-control

This question concerns a local NuGet repository in Artifactory Pro 4.14.2.

We use a service account named `DevNetRunnerSvc` to publish NuGet artifacts to Artifactory. This account is configured with `Deploy/Cache` permissions and **is not configured with `Delete/Overwrite` permissions**.

[image: DevNetRunnerSvc's effective permissions to the repository in question]

However, `DevNetRunnerSvc` is still able to overwrite artifacts in this repository:

[image: Artifact demonstrating modification by DevNetRunnerSvc]

I'd like some assistance in protecting artifacts from any and all overwrites (as is appropriate for a published NuGet package), or a determination that this is a bug that should be forwarded to JFrog.

Additional information:

- The (lightly sanitized) command used to publish artifacts is `jfrog rt upload $(Join-Path $env:CI_PROJECT_DIR "$($env:PACKAGE).$($env:VERSION).nupkg") nuget-org-dev/org/$($env:PACKAGE)/$($env:PACKAGE).$($env:VERSION)-$($env:CI_BUILD_REF_SLUG).nupkg`
- While debugging this issue, I've removed `DevNetRunnerSvc` from all Groups.
- Removing the `Deploy/Cache` permission from `DevNetRunnerSvc`successfully prevents it from publishing artifacts to this repository.
- 'Promoting' a published artifact from this repository to another one *is* prevented appropriately:

  `[Info] Moving artifact: nuget-org-dev/org/org.Infra.Pipeline/org.Infra.Pipeline.0.2.2-master.nupkg to: nuget-org/org/org.Infra.Pipeline/org.Infra.Pipeline.0.2.2.nupkg
  [Error] Artifactory response: 409 Conflict
  {
    "messages": [
      {
        "level": "ERROR",
        "message": "User doesn't have permissions to move 'nuget-org-dev:org/org.Infra.Pipeline/org.Infra.Pipeline.0.2.2-master.nupkg'. Needs delete permissions."
      }
    ]
  }`
- The command used to execute the above is `jfrog rt move "nuget-org-dev/(org)/($($env:PACKAGE))/($($env:PACKAGE).$($env:VERSION))-$($env:CI_BUILD_REF_SLUG)(.nupkg)" "nuget-org/{1}/{2}/{3}{4}"`
- I've added myself as a watcher to this repository. When `DevNetRunnerSvc` overwrites an artifact, I receive the following event notification: `Thu Apr 13 12:25:34 EDT 2017 [devnetrunnersvc/10.228.128.23] [CREATED] nuget-org-dev/org/org.Infra.Pipeline/org.Infra.Pipeline.0.2.2-master.nupkg`

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something but just to make sure, when you remove the "Delete/Overwrite" permissions you are unable to overwrite the artifact? If this is the case, I'm not sure what the issue here? it seems like a perfectly normal behaviour

Comment: When I remove the delete/overwrite permission, I am still able to overwrite the artifact. To say the least this is not expected behavior! Deleting the artifact is blocked like you'd expect. Is there a way I can make the question clearer? Feel free to edit!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was a bug as mentioned in this Jira [RTFACT-14442](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-14442) which is fixed in the later versions. Also, the Artifactory version 4.14.2 has met its [end of life](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+End+of+Life) and JFrog will not take any bugs for this version. I would highly recommend upgrading Artifactory to the latest versions which 6.23 or 7.10.